# fontFamily 'Arial' is not a system font using react-native-textinput-effects

Tags: android, react-native

I have a error when I using react-native-textinput-effects .
This is my error message:

> fontFamily 'Arial' is not a system font and has not been loaded
>   through Expo.Font.loadAsync.
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3382:38
>   in diffProperties
>   - If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
>
> - If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Expo.Font.loadAsync.
> - node_modules\expo\src\Font.js:34:10 in processFontFamily
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3382:38
>     in diffProperties
> - ... 30 more stack frames from framework internals

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Font } from "expo";

import {  Fumi} from 'react-native-textinput-effects';

class Login extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <View style={styles.subview_container}>

   <View style={[styles.card2, { backgroundColor: '#a9ceca' }]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Fumi</Text>
          <Fumi

            label={'Course Name'}
            labelStyle={{ color: '#a3a3a3' }}
            inputStyle={{ color: '#f95a25' }}
            iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
            iconName={'university'}
            iconColor={'#f95a25'}
            iconSize={15}
          />
          <Fumi
            style={styles.input}
            label={'Degree'}
            iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
            iconName={'graduation-cap'}
            iconColor={'#77116a'}
          />
        </View>



        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#555500',
  },
  subview_container: {

  },
card2: {
   padding: 16,
 },
 input: {
   marginTop: 4,
 },
 title: {
   paddingBottom: 16,
   textAlign: 'center',
   color: '#404d5b',
   fontSize: 20,
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   opacity: 0.8,
 }
})

export default Login
```

I tried to load the Arial font using this code but without success :

```
 componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'Arial': require('./assets/fonts/Arial.ttf'),
    });
  }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: check this issue: [https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects/issues/58](https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects/issues/58)

Comment: Tx. I remove fontFamily: 'Arial',on Fumi.js

Answer (score -1):

check this, it is work correctly code for app.js, just adapt for your case

```
  import React from "react";
  import { AppLoading, Font } from "expo";
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

  export default class App extends React.Component {
     state = {
       loaded: false,
     };

     componentWillMount() {
       this._loadAssetsAsync();
     }

     _loadAssetsAsync = async () => {
       await Font.loadAsync({
         diplomata: require("./assets/fonts/DiplomataSC-Regular.ttf"),
       });
       this.setState({ loaded: true });
     };

     render() {
       if (!this.state.loaded) {
         return <AppLoading />;
       }

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.info}>
          Look, you can load this font! Now the question is, should you use it?
          Probably not. But you can load any font.
        </Text>
      </View>
      );
     }
    }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       container: {
         flex: 1,
         backgroundColor: "#fff",
         alignItems: "center",
         justifyContent: "center",
         padding: 30,
       },
       info: {
         fontFamily: "diplomata",
         textAlign: "center",
         fontSize: 14,
       },
   });
```